# Find multivariable function from surface

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I have a table of over 250,000 (x, y, z) coordinates. I'm trying to apply the gradient to find surface characteristics, but I don't know how to obtain the function for the data. It's a pretty complex surface btw, so Mathematica might not even be able to get the function whatsoever.

[image: surface]

Comment: Is this a programming-related question? Or is it maths?

Comment: programming, I want to know if there's a built-in function or method, for instance, "FindFormula" (which I think does not work with R^3 coordinates).

Comment: Try asking here, (sample data would help too) : https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/

Comment: See also https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/253140/how-to-find-appropriate-surface-fit

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.